# Branching and Releasing strategy

Tags: svn, version-control, maven, branch, release

I found some people talking about a few branching strategies. So I thought I'll get some comments on that.

So the project was branched from trunk. Call it branch A. While the work is going on in branch A. They branched from branch A and called it branch B.

They are saying, once branch A features are done, they will merge it back to trunk and when the branch B features are done, it will also merged to the trunk.

Sounds ok to me. Is this ok?

The other suggestions goes like this, Merge branch A to trunk and then do a branch called B.
Which I think will reduce the amount of merging to be done. But, the features in branch A is not yet complete.

What do you think about this situation?
Anything wrong?
Any feedback is welcome. IS there anything we can improve in this strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first approach is OK, but you have to be sure to always have branch B updated with the new changes introduced in branch A. Otherwise if you don't keep them synchronized, these branches will diverge and merging them back on trunk will be a really pain.

SVN merge's are ok if you do them early and often.